# Is it possible to make a visually appealing GUI with JavaFX & Swing?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, javafx

I would like to do a visually appealing / user-friendly GUI in java. Swing is a limited in terms of "skin" customization. I'm thinking about JavaFX, but I don't get it yet,

- what can I achieve with this technology ?
- how hard is it ?
- do you have examples of real-life examples of Swing/JavaFX integration ?

I would like to do something in this spirit of this, which is built on the .NET framework:
[image: GUI example with .NET techno]

original link: http://www.patrickpayet.com/net/?p=329
*edit*: is their any getting started overview sample code that I can read to get a general feeling of the work needed to be done to achieve something in the spirit of the screenshot? maybe something like the miglayout's swing demo http://www.migcalendar.com/miglayout/swingdemoapp.jnlp

*edit2*: I found http://download.java.net/general/openjfx/demos/tutorial.jnlp it's really basic though, linked from http://www.deitel.com/ResourceCenters/Programming/JavaFX/JavaFXTutorialsandDemos/tabid/2187/Default.aspx

Comment: I didn't think I'd ever see the words "Java" and "sexy" in the same sentence in my entire life....

Comment: @Dave 23 years, that's quite young, you still have time to discover new things in your life. Maybe start with http://filthyrichclients.org/ and with Romain Guy's blog http://www.curious-creature.org/category/swing/ to get some enlightenment.

Comment: My point is not my age, my point is that you both Dave and you (and me) have very likely still some things to discover.

Comment: BTW, I don't think that UI on the screenshot is sexy. But maybe it's mostly a design problems.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Doing such a GUI with JavaFX seems to be rather easy.

For a rapid view on the JavaFX echosystem, I would suggest you to take a look at those sites, showing most of the bleeding edge JavaFX technologies :

- [Jonathan Giles blog](http://jonathangiles.net/blog/) on Swing/JavaFX/Griffon
- [Dean Iverson blog](http://pleasingsoftware.blogspot.com/) going more in details about JavaFX components
- [Amy Fowler blog](http://amyfowlersblog.wordpress.com/)
- And finally, take a look at [JavaFX home site](http://javafx.com/) samples.

Comment: thanks a lot, is their any getting started overview sample code that I can read to get a general feeling of the work needed to be done to achieve something in the spirit of the screenshot? maybe something like the miglayout's swing demo http://www.migcalendar.com/miglayout/swingdemoapp.jnlp ?

Comment: Well, having not investigated JavaFX in depth, I can't reply such an answer. However, I know colleagues who have chosen this path, and its seems like the javafx home page may direct you to rather good tutorials.

Comment: I added a javafx webstart demo to the question http://download.java.net/general/openjfx/demos/tutorial.jnlp

Answer (score 7):

Yes, Swing is very customizable. I recommend reading [Filthy Rich Clients](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132413930).

For an example, have a look at [Cezanne L&F](http://www.centigrade.de/en/products/cezanne-look-and-feel-engine).

Answer (score 1):

Swing alone can also create awesome looking UIs. You can explore online for number of plugins and samples to add various features. I'd  recommend you go through [Romain Guy's](http://www.curious-creature.org/category/swing/) Blog & Read his book **Filthy Rich Clients**. I found [this](http://explodingpixels.wordpress.com/) blog  really cool.
Swing won't disappoint you.

Answer (score 0):

Swing's L&F can help you in this case.

The traditional way to customize L&F is to write your own UI classes for all components, which is not easy.

The [Synth L&F](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/synth.html) is included in JRE5 and become mature in JRE6.  With Synth L&F you can customize your own look and feel with images and painter classes. You can also take a look at this [IDE for Synth based L&F](http://www.easynth.com/products/EaSynthLookAndFeelDesigner.html).

Answer (score 0):

Also checkout my entry to the JFXStudio challenge last year:

http://jfxstudio.wordpress.com/2009/11/10/challenge-five-winners/

This is a very simple "Video Poker" game written in just less than 3,000 characters (ie 30 lines of code).  Note that 90% of the graphical elements are images, which gives you an idea of the scope you have for producing "sexy" UIs.

I'll also add that the main elements of this application were written in one evening.  JavaFX is a very powerful tool for UI creation once you get used to it.

Comment: impressive job, thanks for input. That said, where is the code ? in the jars ? I consider this a bug part of some sort of elitism. I have nothing about elitism. That's not hard to put a zip file online nowdays (cf. http://dl.free.fr/), cheers.

Comment: Not sure what you mean about elitism - I mention my intention to supply the code in the comments on that page, though haven't done so yet (it would need a rewrite from its highly condensed current form).  I still intend to do so.  However, the links that others have posted would give you more than enough grounding to write a similar trivial app in JavaFX.

Comment: The link is now "marked private". I guess it means than I cannot access it anymore?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that with JavaFX by writing your own CSS files. Learn more at: [JavaFX CSS Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html)

It is actually not that hard if you are familiar with CSS.